# is it possible targeting a Xamarin iOS project with older SDK version in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I'm newbie in iOS Stuffs. Some months ago, I've developed a Xamarin iOS project connecting to a MacInCloud, and the test worked fine on iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, etc, simulators. Recently MacInCloud XCode upgraded SDK to v11.0 (64-bit) and testing run into some problems, in Visual Studio project properties only show SDK (default) and 11.0. I had to do many change like compatible architectures to only ARM64.

I've checked MacInCloud and I've found many different versions of XCode installed, so I suppose there should be possibility to compile in older version, however SDK drop down in Visual Studio not shows all.

¿How can I do my app can compile in older SDK versions and support new 64-bits and olders iPhones in 32-bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are other versions of Xcode, then you can reference each individually when you try to build. In Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings. Change `Xcode Path` to whatever the name of the previous version of Xcode is called. I would assume it would be something like: `/Applications/Xcode-8.3.3.app`

Depending on how old of a version of Xcode you want, you might have to jump through some more hoops (e.g. Xamarin.iOS 11.0 might not be compatible with an **old** version of Xcode).

Comment: valdetero, ¿the version of SDK shown in Visual Studio refers is to the version of Xamarin iOS?

Comment: Help -> About. What's next to Xamarin.iOS is the SDK version.